# java variable to retain value, not update

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Sorry, but I'm loosing my mind. I'm trying to create a variable that will hold the selection of a `JTree` for later use. I can't for the life of me figure out how to set that variable without it updating with later changes the selection in the Jtree that I'm trying to preserve:

This is where I'm trying to capture the `JTree` selection:

```
CopySelection = FormTree.getSelectionModel();
```

I want the **CopySelection** to remain unchanged until I need it.

CopySelection is defined as:

```
public TreeSelectionModel CopySelection;
```

When I try to use **CopySelection** later on, it will have updated with changes made to the selection in the JTree, but I don't want that.

Comment: Why are you saving the selection model and not a reference to the item(s) that have been selected?

Comment: Possibly because I'm dumb, but I have no idea of knowing how may paths may be in there. It could be 1 or 2 or hundreds. I figured it was easier to just keep the entire selection model with parents and all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your getSelectionModel() method is built. While C++ methods usually return a copy of the object, in Java, the methods return pointers to the object. Therefore, you need to create a new object to be returned, rather than returning the object itself. I'll leave you an example of a Java app I'm developing here:

```
public ChessBoard copyChessBoard() {
    ChessBoard newboard = new ChessBoard();
    this.copyTo(newboard);
    return newboard;
}
```

The copyTo() function, simply iterates through the elements, copying each and one of them into the new board in my case (creating new elements). It seems time consuming (and it is), but if you have an iterator built inside your data structure, it shouldn't be more than an O(n) complexity.

Needless to say, this new element is completely independent from the first one.

Good luck and let me know if it is what you needed!

PS: As you may have guessed, the copySelectionModel() (my copyChessBoard() method), should replace your getSelectionModel().